# How to add a custom template for fieldset in ui-component form in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.2, ui-form, fieldsets, custom-template

I have two filed sets in ui component form , Now I wish to Add custom template for one of the field set.Is it possible in uicomponent form to add custom template for a field set. Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use **HtmlContent component** for adding a custom template to a UI fieldset

Referred a customer module for adding a template in UI component as follows,

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <htmlContent name="customer_edit_tab_view">
       <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="Magento_Customer::tab/view.phtml">
         <arguments>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
                <argument name="tab_label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer View</argument>
         </arguments>
         <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo" name="personal_info" template="Magento_Customer::tab/view/personal_info.phtml"/>
       </block>
    </htmlContent>
</form>
```

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-htmlcontent.html

Comment: Hi Haritha, I need to add drop down field in uiform, which consists category collection. Is this possible in ui-component form

Comment: Can you try following the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157168/magento-2-1-2-ui-component-formelement-select-from-multiple-dropdowns

Comment: this solution show html successfully, but can't catch it as a params in save action.